# Where is the code that builds the Ubuntu packages?

Tags: ros, ros2, deb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I was hoping to find some ground truth for what comes with the .deb packages and how they are built.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297945/where-is-the-code-that-builds-the-ubuntu-packages?/) by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2018-07-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

[bloom](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/bloom/) is the tool in ROS which generates the Debian control files based on the metadata available in the package manifest.

[ros_buildfarm](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/ros_buildfarm/) is the Python package which drives the buildfarm which actually produces the `.deb` files. But uultimately it simply invokes `gbp buildpackage` and `apt-src build`.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [calvertdw](https://answers.ros.org/users/29941/calvertdw/) on 2018-07-19**:
It seems the ROS2 config is here: https://github.com/ros2/ci

**Comment by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) on 2018-07-19**:
That repository doesn't contain any logic to create Debian packages. It only creates logic for CI jobs.